# PokerStars lets you play from PC, but blocks on phone?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-stars

I live in eastern EU country and I play PokerStars on my desktop PC almost every day. I have confirmed account, identity, etc.

But if I download PokerStars app on Android it tells me to turn on Location and gives me error saying my country is restricted?

I'm on same exact location (same room) sitting next to my PC and I can play on it, but I can't play on phone using Wi-fi from same ISP as my desktop router?

How does any of this make any sense?

Before you say to stick with PC only then, problem is I can't play on PokerStars on phone while traveling (within same country).

I just want someone to explain some logical sense into this. PokerStars also has absolutely no support to respond to this, so I posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently PokerStars has different clients for each region, e.g. EU has separate client.

So how did I end up with wrong client?

1. Old phone with old OS.
2. PokerStars app does not show on Play Store because of too old Android OS.
3. Ended up downloading wrong .apk installer from Google.

How it was solved:

1. Direct message PokerStars support on Twitter and they will send you the right installer.